# Angular 2 URL changes unexpectedly after component load

Tags: angular

I have a simple Angular 2 app, set up as follows:

forchild routes for /hosts to display a component for a list of hosts and /host:id to display a detail component for a specific host.

When i go to /hosts i get the list of hosts no problems. A field on each row has a link to /host:id. If i click on a specific row item the detail component displays fine. for a brief moment i see /host/1234 and then the URL changes back to /hosts. the detail component stays on the screen.

i have a host module set up with the following routes

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'hosts', component: HostListComponent},
  { path: 'host/:id', component: HostDetailsComponent}
])
```

I want the url to stay on /host/1234 when i navigate to it and not go back to /hosts

any ideas?

thanks

Matt

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console  ?

Comment: @Skeptor [**angular-routing tag**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-routing/info) refers to ng1 route (which isn't the case here).

Comment: my bad, thanks for updating.

Comment: yes.. i am getting some errors.. looks like when im trying to output object values in the html. If i comment these out, then it works as expected. now i just have to figure out how to fix those other errors. thanks chaps! :)

Answer (score 0):

simple newbie mistake. i didnt have an ngif in my html template and this was causing undefined errors. Because of these errors i was getting the weird routing behaviour. which in hindsight, makes sense.

Next time i will check the console BEFORE i post :)

thanks all.